# Scheme maxing a quoted list

Tags: scheme, racket

So I have written this function that returns a list of numbers in this format:

```
'(1 2 5 6 7 2)
```

Now I need to find the maximum value of this list, but the max function doesn't seem to work with this type of list. How would I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is

```
> (max 1 2 5 6 7 2)
7
```

Since your arguments are in a list, use `apply`:

```
> (apply max '(1 2 5 6 7 2))
7
```

See also [here](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/procedures.html?q=apply#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/base..rkt%29._apply%29%29).

Comment: What exactly does apply do? I'm a bit confused by it.

Comment: `max` is a procedure that takes one or more parameters, so you code `(max n1 ...)`. Simply put, `apply` transforms `(max '(n1 ...))` into `(max n1 ...)`

Comment: @Seeker Do you know Python or Ruby, and their "splatting" operator? (`foo(bar, *baz)`) `apply` is the Scheme version of the same concept.